# Getting column values from various tables from a result set using UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

I have a problem where I am trying to fetch the percentage value of each discount, however the complicated part is that there are 2 types of discounts. Flexible discount and Fixed discount. I am trying to fetch the percentages of all discounts and depending on what the type of discount is e.g. Fixed I go into the Fixed Discount table and retrieve the percentage else the percentage from the FlexiBand discount table.

My tables and their attributes:

```
Discount:
DiscountID,
Name,
Type

FixedDiscount:
DiscountID,
Percentage

FlexibleDiscount:
DiscountID

FlexiBand:
UpperBound,
PercentageRate,
DiscountID
```

I received the error `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'PercentageRate' not found.`

When I did this:

```
 public ArrayList<Discount> getDiscounts() throws SQLException {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    ArrayList<Discount> discount = new ArrayList<Discount>();

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abpp034?user=abpp034&password=120001772");

    stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Discount.DiscountID, Discount.Type, FixedDiscount.Percentage\n" +
"FROM Discount\n" +
"INNER JOIN FixedDiscount\n" +
"ON Discount.DiscountID = FixedDiscount.DiscountID\n" +
"\n" +
"UNION\n" +
"\n" +
"SELECT Discount.DiscountID, Discount.Type, FlexiBand.PercentageRate\n" +
"FROM Discount\n" +
"INNER JOIN FlexiBand\n" +
"ON Discount.DiscountID = FlexiBand.DiscountID");


    try {

        while (rs.next()) {

            Discount d = new Discount();
            Fixed_Discount fd = new Fixed_Discount();
            FlexiBand fb = new FlexiBand();                
            d.setDiscountId(rs.getInt("DiscountID"));
            d.setType(rs.getString("Type"));      
            fd.setPercentage(rs.getInt("Percentage"));
            fb.setPercentageRate(rs.getInt("PercentageRate"));



            discount.add(d);
            discount.add(fd);
            discount.add(fb);

        }

        } finally {

        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
            }
        }
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println(se.getErrorCode());
            }
        }
    }

    return discount;

    }
```

What is wierd is that PercentageRate does indeed exist in the table FlexiBand but I think the problem is after the UNION the next statement isn't being identified properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove the username and password info from the connection string.
Do both queries fire cleanly when run independently? Is your RDBMS mysql or sql-server?